# Facebook SDK: SharePhotoContent Not Working

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

am developing an app with sharing text and multiple images in a single post  using facebook sdk. I used the following code, but nothing happens in my  fb wall post. Whats wrong in the code please anybody help. thanks in advance.

```
private void publishImage() {

    ArrayList<SharePhoto> sharePhotos = new ArrayList<>();
    int imageFolderSize;
    File  imageFolder = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), "attachments/images");
    if( imageFolder.exists()) {     
        imageFolderSize = imageFolder.listFiles().length;
        ArrayList<File> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
        if (imageFolder.exists()) {              
            Collections.addAll(attachments, imageFolder.listFiles());
        }

        if (imageFolderSize > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++) {
                File file = attachments.get(i);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    if (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".png")) {
                        try {
                            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()))
                                    .setCaption("Welcome To Facebook Photo Sharing on steroids!")
                                    .build();
                            sharePhotos.add(photo);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            RMLog.debug("Execp: e"+e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }                   
            }
        }
    }

SharePhotoContent scontent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhotos(sharePhotos
            ).build();
    if(ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class))
    {   ShareApi.share(scontent, null);          
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Succsesfully posted on your wall",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }  

}
```

Comment: works great, but i cant see the caption in my post....please help me.I can see only the images in my wall, is there any other way to the caption text along with the images,,,?

Comment: Facebook doesn’t always show the caption in newsfeed. Go check the detail view of the photo – if it shows there, then everything worked correctly, and there is nothing more you can do about it.

Comment: Thank you CBroe ,  but  i can see only the image, how to see the detail view of the photo. there is nothing else found in the post.

Comment: “how to see the detail view of the photo” – by clicking on it, so that the photo viewer mode opens …

Comment: yeah...you are right,  but it showing only that corresponding image not showing any captions in it....Thank u..